# C++ Segmentation fault: 11 Error, while coding linkedlist that adds two numbers

Tags: c++

I have a code like below :

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode
{
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr){} 
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr){} 
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next){}
};

void print(ListNode *head) {
    ListNode *l = head;
    while (l)
    {
        std::cout << "val is " << l->val << std::endl;
        l = l->next;
    }
}

ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2)
{
    int sum = 0, quo = 0, rem = 0;
    ListNode *head = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *curr, *prev = nullptr;
    while (l1 || l2)
    {
        // Calculate value
        sum = (l1->val + l2->val + quo);
        quo = sum / 10;
        rem = sum - quo * 10;

        // Add node
        if(prev == nullptr) {
            curr = head;
        } else {
            curr = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            prev->next = curr;
        }
        curr->val = rem;
        prev = curr;
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return head;
}



int main() {
    ListNode *node1_1 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node1_2 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node1_3 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node1_1->val = 2;
    node1_2->val = 4;
    node1_3->val = 3;
    node1_1->next = node1_2;
    node1_2->next = node1_3;

    ListNode *node2_1 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node2_2 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node2_3 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node2_1->val = 5;
    node2_2->val = 6;
    node2_3->val = 4;
    node2_1->next = node2_2;
    node2_2->next = node2_3;

    free(node1_1);
    free(node1_2);
    free(node1_3);
    free(node2_1);
    free(node2_2);
    free(node2_3);

    print(addTwoNumbers(node1_1, node2_1));
}
```

The problem is, when I am trying to run this code on vscode,
I keep getting error :

`/bin/sh: line 1: 96278 Segmentation fault: 11  "/Users/cpp/"leet_add_two_nums`

I suspect that this issue is related to malloc, but cannot find a clue.

I have tried to free after malloc, but that was not the problem.

I am very new to C++, can anyone help?

Also, I would really appreciate if anyone tell me how I could improve my code!

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: You're including `iostream`, so I'm assuming this really is C++ and not C...in which case, **don't use raw `malloc` and `free`!!** *At least* use `new` and `delete`, but even better would be switching to smart pointers.

Comment: @jamesdean It is a good idea to call these functions print(addTwoNumbers(node1_1, node2_1)); after deleting all nodes.:)

Comment: I'm not 100% sold on smart pointers with linked lists. I do some big lists.

Comment: @Vlad I'm guessing you mean "It is NOT a good idea [...]"?

Comment: Your ListNode's were never initialized, because they were not constructed; they were only allocated.  The print is using the nodes that were just freed.  Your addTwoNumbers routine will fail if the two node structures are of different lengths.

Comment: @Eljay Can you clarify a bit more on "ListNode's were never initialized, because they were not constructed; they were only allocated."? btw, thanks so much for all the corrections!

Answer (score 1):

```
while (l1 || l2)
```

This means "while either `l1` is not `nullptr` OR `l2` is not `nullptr`, keep looping!

You want an AND there:

```
while(l1 && l2)
```

Furthermore, you free all the nodes of your list before you call `addTwoNumbers`! Move your `addTwoNumbers` call up to before all the `free`'s.

See it run here: https://ideone.com/f4kBIh

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be fixed easily by replacing ***malloc*** with '***new***'

Use of '**new**' gives these benefits:

- Make the program resilient to common issues with malloc.
- Remove the need for the explicit calls to 'free'.

**Here is the working code with malloc replaced by new:**

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr){} 
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr){} 
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next){}
};

void print(ListNode *head) {
    ListNode *l = head;
    while (l) {
        std::cout << "val is " << l->val << std::endl;
        l = l->next;
    }
}

ListNode *addTwoNumbers(ListNode *l1, ListNode *l2) {
    int sum = 0, quo = 0, rem = 0;
    ListNode *head = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    ListNode *curr, *prev = nullptr;
    while (l1 || l2) {
        // Calculate value
        sum = (l1->val + l2->val + quo);
        quo = sum / 10;
        rem = sum - quo * 10;

        // Add node
        if(prev == nullptr) {
            curr = head;
        } else {
            curr = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
            prev->next = curr;
        }
        curr->val = rem;
        prev = curr;
        l1 = l1->next;
        l2 = l2->next;
    }
    return head;
}

int main() {
    ListNode *node1_1 = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    ListNode *node1_2 =  new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    ListNode *node1_3 =  new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    node1_1->val = 2;
    node1_2->val = 4;
    node1_3->val = 3;
    node1_1->next = node1_2;
    node1_2->next = node1_3;

    ListNode *node2_1 = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    ListNode *node2_2 = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    ListNode *node2_3 = new ListNode[(sizeof(ListNode))];
    node2_1->val = 5;
    node2_2->val = 6;
    node2_3->val = 4;
    node2_1->next = node2_2;
    node2_2->next = node2_3;

    print(addTwoNumbers(node1_1, node2_1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
val is 7
val is 0
val is 8
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it okay to say that new is always preferred over malloc in c++?

Comment: Yes. Definitely. It is always better to use new instead of malloc in all applications. 'new' is the convenient and defect-free way to initialize objects. 'malloc' is a legacy feature from C language and hence may be used for legacy support only.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so some comments about this code

Constructors are great in classes, but if you use C malloc then the constructor is not executed.

Use `new` and `delete` for your classes/structs e.g. ListNode, that way next will actually be null as you specify in your constructor, otherwise it will be uninitialized

Your while loop

```
while (l1 || l2)
```

will continue until *both* are null, but if one of them happens to turn to null you will derereference it since the other is potentially not null:

```
    l1 = l1->next;
    l2 = l2->next;
```

(btw use better variable names, there is no advantage using short, cryptic variable names)

In you main function - you have already freed the memory of node1_1 and node1_2 but still use it in your function call `print(addTwoNumbers(node1_1,node2_1))`

```
int main() {
    ListNode *node1_1 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node1_2 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node1_3 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node1_1->val = 2;
    node1_2->val = 4;
    node1_3->val = 3;
    node1_1->next = node1_2;
    node1_2->next = node1_3;

    ListNode *node2_1 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node2_2 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    ListNode *node2_3 = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    node2_1->val = 5;
    node2_2->val = 6;
    node2_3->val = 4;
    node2_1->next = node2_2;
    node2_2->next = node2_3;

    free(node1_1);
    free(node1_2);
    free(node1_3);
    free(node2_1);
    free(node2_2);
    free(node2_3);

    print(addTwoNumbers(node1_1, node2_1));  <<== node1_1,node2_1, already freed
}
```

Instead do something like this

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto node1_1 = new ListNode;
    auto node1_2 = new ListNode;
    auto node1_3 = new ListNode;

    node1_1->val = 2;
    node1_2->val = 4;
    node1_3->val = 3;

    node1_1->next = node1_2;
    node1_2->next = node1_3;

    ListNode *node2_1 = new ListNode;
    ListNode *node2_2 = new ListNode;
    ListNode *node2_3 = new ListNode;

    node2_1->val = 5;
    node2_2->val = 6;
    node2_3->val = 4;

    node2_1->next = node2_2;
    node2_2->next = node2_3;

    std::cout << addTwoNumbers(node1_1, node2_1); 

    delete node1_1;
    delete node1_2;
    delete node1_3;
    delete node2_1;
    delete node2_2;
    delete node2_3;
}
```

Comment: good, that is what it is all about here at SO. sometimes people seem to forget that.